# colorWithPatternImage in a retina

Tags: ios

I am having some issues with the colorWithPatternImage. 
The image stretched out in a retina screen, I looked around and could't a solution that worked for me.

Here is what I have:

> tblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"list_container.png"]];

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a hi-res version of the pattern save as `list_container@2x.png`.